# How do you set a default value for a Html.TextBoxFor( ... ) text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, textbox

I know that you can create a textbox using ASP.NET that will automatically be filled with whatever the value in the model is by using

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { id = "FirstName", placeholder = "[First Name]" }) %>
```

Is there a way to give it a default value if `model.FirstName` is null?

I've tried adding a value attribute, but that didn't work.

I also can't pass in a model with that value included, because it will affect other areas of the form.

Comment: same idea. however, as I stated in my question, I tried both the top voted answer, and the accepted answer, and neither worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could change the model property to return a default value if it's null (or setting default values when creating the model) or you can use the `Html.TextBox` helper instead of `Html.TextBoxFor`:

```
<%: Html.TextBox("FirstName", Model.FirstName ?? "The default value", new { id = "FirstName", placeholder = "[First Name]" }) %>
```

or use the value-attribute:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @Value = "The default value", id = "FirstName", placeholder = "[First Name]" }) %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Would something like a watermark work for what you're trying to accomplish?

There are a number of different implementation for jquery - [this](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/TinyWatermark) looks like it would work, and there is an option to use the title attribute for the watermark, which could be part of your model.